# Functor question in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class myFunctorClass
{
public:
    myFunctorClass(int x) : _x(x) {}
    int oprator() (int y) {return _x + y;}
private:
    int _x;
}

int main(void)
   {
       myFunctorClass addFive(5);
       std::cout << addFive(6);
       std::cin.get();
       return 0;
   }
```

This is example code from here:
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html

But I got errors:

```
Error   5   error C2065: 'y' : undeclared identifier
```

and

```
Error   2   error C2628: 'myFunctorClass' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
```

I don't have gcc now. Is this supposed to be compile under gcc or linux environment?
How to change it work in Visual Studio?

Update:
Problem solved.
I mis-spell operator
I lost one semicolon.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try reading the error the compiler gave you? That sometimes helps. > Error 2 error C2628: 'myFunctorClass' followed by 'int' is illegal (**did you forget a ';'?**) What does that tell you?

Comment: I doubt the compiler knows "oprator".

Comment: @sbi: Maybe Visual *Stodio* 2010 implements an `oprator` keyword :-)

Comment: +1 for cutting-and-pasting the *actual* code. For errors such as these, it is vital to provide a minimal, complete sample program, as @David did. See http://ssccee.org/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two problems here -- in C++, unlike C# / Java, etc., you need a semicolon after your class declaration. The other issue is that you have misspelled "operator."